# WSL Jupyter Server VS Code Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, wsl-2

Hey i'm having hard time finding issue on this topic

I'm initating jupyter notebook with --allow-root --allow_origin='*' --no-browser  on my wsl2

Run VS Code from WSL2:

(1)Option Of Choosing Another kernel on right side on my .ipynb file

(2) Select another kernel

(3) Choosing Exisitng Jupyter Server

(4)Pasting the url with token of previously initiated Jupyter Server

And then nothing happens and it tells me choose another kernel again back to (2) window, if i'm repating process (2)>>(3)>>(4) it tells me that server URl already exists. Mean time in Jupyter Log Appears Error 403 Forbidden. Problem i can't connect to my Jupyter Server URl from VS Code.
I tried to fully uninstall vs code with user data and clean install again same issue. Url opens perfectly on my browser. In case i need to Connect to server(i know i can use kernel directly)

It was working before but i don't know what i did specifically to make this problem occur

Clean installing my wsl2 is possible but i hope it can avoided(Lot of changes and tweaks)

Comment: I tried to clean install wsl2 but problems i still here (